# How can I use the system volume for my sound?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am playing a sound in my app using the following code:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/samsung_whistle.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
player.numberOfLoops = 0;
[player play];
```

This seems to work, however when I set the system volume (using the hardware buttons on the device) it doesn't have any effect on my sound. If I set the volume all the way down (so the device says "sounds off") I can still hear my sound playing. And if I set the volume all the way up my sound is not played any louder.

I know that I can set the volume of my sound with

```
player.volume = someFloatBetween0And1;
```

But this hardcodes the volume. How can I retrieve the system sound volume and set it for my sound, so users can properly adjust their volume?

Comment: System sound is universal sound. You have no control on it. But your application sound's output will be according to system time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The volume you set on your player and the system volume are independent.

It's like when you watch a movie in your favorite video player. It has a settable volume. Still, you have the system volume (in your system tray perhaps) that you can set **independently** from the video player volume.

If the system volume is at 50% and your player's volume is at 50% as well, the sound is 4 times weaker than if both are at 100%.

Conclusion: if your player is set at 100% and the system volume is 0% then... silence. Which is a good use case. Because if apps could access the system volume, when I get a phone call I would need to go to each app and get the darn sound level to 0 :D

Comment: I would understand if this was true, but when I set the player's volume to 100% and the system volume to 0% I can still hear it at 100%.....

Comment: After removing the app from the device and cleaning my project, it seems to work. Very strange... Anyway, thank you for the explanation, it is indeed as you say.

Comment: Good explanation! Is your explanation from Apple Documentation or other doc？

Comment: @songgeb I don't remember :)) It was almost 6 years ago, plus is objective-c still alive? Reading it, at least in part I think it is based on personal experience with VLC :))